# ORM supporting immutable classes

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, scala, types

Which ORM supports a domain model of **immutable** types?

I would like to write classes like the following (or the Scala equivalent):

```
class A {
  private final C c; //not mutable

  A(B b) {
     //init c
  }

  A doSomething(B b) {
     // build a new A
  }
}
```

The ORM has to **initialized the object with the constructor**. So it is possible to check invariants in the constructor. Default constructor and field/setter access to intialize is not sufficient and complicates the class' implementation.

Working with **collections** should be supported. If a collection is changed it should create a copy from the user perspective. (Rendering the old collection state stale. But user code can still work on (or at least read) it.) Much like the [persistent data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) work.

Some words about the motivation. Suppose you have a FP-style domain object model. Now you want to persist this to a database. Who do you do that? You want to do as much as you can in a pure functional style until the evil sides effect come in. If your domain object model is not immutable you can for example not share the objects between threads. You have to copy, cache or use locks. So unless your ORM supports immutable types your constrainted in your choice of solution.

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE:** I created a project focused on solving this problem called [**JIRM**](https://github.com/agentgt/jirm):
https://github.com/agentgt/jirm

I just found this question after implementing my own using [Spring JDBC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/jdbc.html) and [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org) Object Mapper. Basically I just needed some bare minimum SQL <-> immutable object mapping.

In short I just use **[Springs RowMapper](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html)** and **[Jackson's ObjectMapper](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.7.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html)** to map Objects back and forth from the database. I use JPA annotations just for metadata (like column name etc...). **If people are interested I will clean it up and put it on github** (right now its only in my startup's private repo).

Here is a rough idea how it works here is an example bean (*notice how all the fields are final*):

```
//skip imports for brevity
public class TestBean {

    @Id
    private final String stringProp;
    private final long longProp;
    @Column(name="timets")
    private final Calendar timeTS;

    @JsonCreator
    public TestBean(
            @JsonProperty("stringProp") String stringProp, 
            @JsonProperty("longProp") long longProp,
            @JsonProperty("timeTS") Calendar timeTS ) {
        super();
        this.stringProp = stringProp;
        this.longProp = longProp;
        this.timeTS = timeTS;
    }

    public String getStringProp() {
        return stringProp;
    }
    public long getLongProp() {
        return longProp;
    }

    public Calendar getTimeTS() {
        return timeTS;
    }

}
```

Here what the [RowMapper](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html) looks like (notice it mainly delegats to Springs ColumnMapRowMapper and then uses Jackson's objectmapper):

```
public class SqlObjectRowMapper<T> implements RowMapper<T> {

    private final SqlObjectDefinition<T> definition;
    private final ColumnMapRowMapper mapRowMapper;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;


    public SqlObjectRowMapper(SqlObjectDefinition<T> definition, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        super();
        this.definition = definition;
        this.mapRowMapper = new SqlObjectMapRowMapper(definition);
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    public SqlObjectRowMapper(Class<T> k) {
        this(SqlObjectDefinition.fromClass(k), new ObjectMapper());
    }


    @Override
    public T mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        Map<String, Object> m = mapRowMapper.mapRow(rs, rowNum);
        return objectMapper.convertValue(m, definition.getObjectType());
    }

}
```

Now I just took Spring JDBCTemplate and gave it a *fluent* wrapper. Here are some examples:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    dao = new SqlObjectDao<TestBean>(new JdbcTemplate(ds), TestBean.class);

}

@Test
public void testAll() throws Exception {
    TestBean t = new TestBean(IdUtils.generateRandomUUIDString(), 2L, Calendar.getInstance());
    dao.insert(t);
    List<TestBean> list = dao.queryForListByFilter("stringProp", "hello");
    List<TestBean> otherList = dao.select().where("stringProp", "hello").forList();
    assertEquals(list, otherList);
    long count = dao.select().forCount();
    assertTrue(count > 0);

    TestBean newT = new TestBean(t.getStringProp(), 50, Calendar.getInstance());
    dao.update(newT);
    TestBean reloaded = dao.reload(newT);
    assertTrue(reloaded != newT);
    assertTrue(reloaded.getStringProp().equals(newT.getStringProp()));
    assertNotNull(list);

}

@Test
public void testAdding() throws Exception {
    //This will do a UPDATE test_bean SET longProp = longProp + 100
    int i = dao.update().add("longProp", 100).update();
    assertTrue(i > 0);

}

@Test
public void testRowMapper() throws Exception {
    List<Crap> craps = dao.query("select string_prop as name from test_bean limit ?", Crap.class, 2);
    System.out.println(craps.get(0).getName());

    craps = dao.query("select string_prop as name from test_bean limit ?")
                .with(2)
                .forList(Crap.class);

    Crap c = dao.query("select string_prop as name from test_bean limit ?")
                .with(1)
                .forObject(Crap.class);

    Optional<Crap> absent 
        = dao.query("select string_prop as name from test_bean where string_prop = ? limit ?")
            .with("never")
            .with(1)
            .forOptional(Crap.class);

    assertTrue(! absent.isPresent());

}

public static class Crap {

    private final String name;

    @JsonCreator
    public Crap(@JsonProperty ("name") String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

Notice in the above how easy it is to map any query into immutable POJO's. That is you don't need it 1-to-1 of entity to table. Also notice the use of [Guava's optionals](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) (last query.. scroll down). I really hate how ORM's either throw exceptions or return `null`.

Let me know if you like it and I'll spend the time putting it on github (only teste with postgresql). Otherwise with the info above you can easily implement your own using Spring JDBC. I'm starting to really dig it because immutable objects are easier to understand and think about.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the source. Feel free to put it on GitHub! Curious use of `Optional`. I'm not sure why this is better than using `null`?

Comment: Very nice. I'll have to have a closer look ASAP!

Comment: I have just tried to use your project and it seems to be very outdated, or it least it depends on outdated artifacts. It would be great if you would bring it up-to-date.

Answer (score 5):

Hibernate has the [`@Immutable`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/api/org/hibernate/annotations/Immutable.html) annotation.

And [here is a guide](http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2007/09/domain-modeling-with-jpa-gotchas-part-1.html).

Comment: As far as I know Hibernate does not support final fields and "constructor injection" of values.

Comment: do you need `final`? You can just limit it with the lack of setters.

Comment: Wouldn't be immutable otherwise. I don't like frameworks to restrict my choice of language features.

Comment: If it is not final and the ORM is not forced to use the constructor to initialize the instance things get more complicated that they should (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624392/check-invariants-in-hibernate-mapped-classes).

Comment: You're wrong about NH: it supports read-only entity semantics, which is different to common definition of immutable object. Think about collections.

Comment: just that it's about hibernate, not NH :)

Answer (score 3):

Though not a *real* ORM, MyBatis may able to do this. I didn't try it though.

http://mybatis.org/java.html

Comment: Yep, MyBatis supports immutable classes quite well: you can even set your fields to final. See the constructor section for mapping them: http://www.mybatis.org/core/sqlmap-xml.html

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there are no ORMs for .NET supporting this feature exactly as you wish. But you can take a look at BLTookit and LINQ to SQL - both provide update-by-comparison semantics and always return new objects on materialization. That's nearly what you need, but I'm not sure about collections there.

Btw, why you need this feature? I'm aware about pure functional languages & benefits of purely imutable objects (e.g. complete thread safety). But in case with ORM all the things you do with such objects are finally transformed to a sequence of SQL commands anyway. So I admit the benefits of using such objects are vaporous here.

Comment: See edit. The problem is not in the persistence part but in the layers that build on the domain objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Ebean and OpenJPA (and I think you can do this with Hibernate but not sure). The ORM (Ebean/OpenJPA) will generate a default constructor (assuming the bean doesn't have one) and actually set the values of the 'final' fields. This sounds a bit odd but final fields are not always strictly final per say.

Answer (score 0):

[SORM](http://sorm-framework.org/) is a new Scala ORM which does exactly what you want. The code below will explain it better than any words:

```
// Declare a model:
case class Artist ( name : String, genres : Set[Genre] )
case class Genre ( name : String ) 

// Initialize SORM, automatically generating schema:
import sorm._
object Db extends Instance (
  entities = Set() + Entity[Artist]() + Entity[Genre](),
  url = "jdbc:h2:mem:test"
)

// Store values in the db:
val metal = Db.save( Genre("Metal") )
val rock = Db.save( Genre("Rock") )
Db.save( Artist("Metallica", Set() + metal + rock) )
Db.save( Artist("Dire Straits", Set() + rock) )

// Retrieve values from the db:
val metallica = Db.query[Artist].whereEqual("name", "Metallica").fetchOne() // Option[Artist]
val rockArtists = Db.query[Artist].whereEqual("genres.name", "Rock").fetch() // Stream[Artist]
```

Comment: How should an update work? Lets say I query an immutable object "a" and do something like b = a.map(f: MyType => MyType) to get an updated "copy" of "a". Now "a" is outdated and "b" is up-to-date and I would like to store "b" as the update of "a". I guess Db.save(b) will result in an Insert and now "a" and "b" are both stored. I would like to tell SORM to replace "a" by "b". Ideally without dealing with the id, because SORM want's the id to be database internal (Not the worst idea if you ask me).

Comment: @user573215 If `val b = a.copy(..)` then `Db.save(b)` will result in appropriate rows getting **updated**, not inserted. Such a behaviour is achieved with help of [Persisted trait](http://sorm-framework.org/Documentation.html#persisted_trait_and_ids), which is basically there to transparently carry the identification information with entities.

Comment: Looking at your example I see immutable Scala code backed by a mutable database.  Imagine that a single was found of Dire Straits playing Metal.  How many rows in the Artist table in the database would they then take up?  Would you be able query what Dire Straits played before the Metal single was found, versus what we know they play now?  Which "immutable" version of Dire Straits would win, or would they become two bands?

Comment: @GlenPeterson Consider the immutable value to be a snapshot of the state in DB. The framework implicitly manages the association with records in the DB. When you persist an updated value, it mutates the appropriate data in the DB instead of inserting duplicate data as you suspected. [Here are the docs on how it actually is achieved](http://sorm-framework.org/Documentation.html#persisted_trait_and_ids).