# What is the best scala-like persistence framework available right now?

Tags: database, scala, frameworks, persistence

What is the best scala-like persistence framework available right now?

Hibernate works, but it's not very scala-like. It insists on using annotations, no-arg constructors, doesn't work with anonymous class instances, doesn't work with scala collections, has an outdated string-based query model, etc.

I'm looking for something that really fits Scala. Does it exist? Or do I have to make it?

Comment: If you find one let me know: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698665/orm-supporting-immutable-classes :-) (JPA2 query support is typed - at least for Java - as it generates types on the fly.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Squeryl](http://max-l.github.com/Squeryl/introduction.html) is a strongly typed, LINQ like persistence framework written entirely in Scala.
In any case, it looks very promising. There's also [ScalaQuery](http://szeiger.de/blog/category/scala/scala-query/) by Stephan Zeiger, which has a similar approach.

I haven't tried these two out yet, but will likely do so in the very near future.

Answer (score 1):

Old question and that's probably why no one mentioned [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/) at the time, but that's a good choice nowadays. It's developed by Typesafe, so there's some assurance of quality and continuous development that other frameworks might not have.

Anyway, this link might be a good source for anyone looking for other options: http://manuel.bernhardt.io/2014/02/04/a-quick-tour-of-relational-database-access-with-scala/.

Answer (score 0):

[Lift](http://liftweb.net/) has a persistence framework in scala, but it's integrated with the web framework and is a bit specialized.

Answer (score 0):

I've not gotten a chance to evaluate it personally, but it looks like [eBean](http://www.avaje.org/) is very Scala friendly. It even supports Scala types (as of Release 2.6.1).

Comment: This looks very bloated. Really, all those getters and setters are ugly as hell. We don't need that in scala. There is no point to do that in scala.

Comment: You don't need Java Getters and Setters. Ebean can detect that the 'bean' is a Scala bean and use 'Scala Properties'.